# output individual values from one key JSON jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to output values from an array that has one key and multiple values in a [JSON file](http://www.reneinla.com/kris/scripts/print.json). I've managed to output the values using `$.each()`, but what happens is that the value is returned as an array, because it is an array! I want to output each value individually so that the output is not an array:

`<img src="one-value-output" />`

`<img src="two-value-output" />`

etc...

**JSON**

```
var dataJson = "http://www.reneinla.com/kris/scripts/print.json";
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{  
  "printImages":[  
      "http://reneinla.com/kris/images/print/2008-06_KZO_TEN_01.jpg",
      "...",
      "http://reneinla.com/kris/images/print/2008-06_KZO_TEN_03.jpg"
 ]
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var dataJson = "http://www.reneinla.com/kris/scripts/print.json";
//var dataArr = $.parseJSON(dataJson);
  $.getJSON(dataJson, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
    console.log( v );
  });
});
```

I'd like to be able to output each value and append it to an src attribute, but wanted to see the `console.log` output first.

**First Question**

How do you print out, `console.log`, all the values from the json file?

**Second Question**

Is this the right approach to what i'm trying to achieve? I thought I'd use a JSON file because I have 88 values that need to be appended into the DOM. I could make the JSON file into an object, in my js file, but wanted to keep it more organized and efficient. This is still fairly new, so any insight here would be appreciated. Thanks and regards!

**EDIT**

I was able to get my desired result using this code:

```
var dataJson = "http://www.reneinla.com/kris/scripts/print.json";
//var dataArr = $.parseJSON(dataJson);
  $.getJSON(dataJson, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
      var i = 0;
      for (i; i < v.length; i++){
        console.log( v[i] );
      }
    });
  });
```

Hooray!

Comment: Your edit will work, but you'd be better off just using `data.printImages`

Comment: @AndrewR - can you clarify why I should be using data.printImages instead? I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept (still new to me). Thanks

Comment: Sure. The edit you made has 2 loops, because $.each internally also uses a `for` loop. (Actually `for ( i in obj)` for something passed in that is not an array.) When you do `$.each(data`, `data` is an object, so you are looping through the object properties. The object has 1 property `printImages` which is an array. What you really want to be looping through is that array, which is what the edit you made does. It's more efficient and shorter code to use `$.each(data.printImages` because that's the array you are interested in.

Comment: amazing! I wasn't aware that you could add the property to the object, `data`.  After reading the `.each` [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), it clearly states you can iterate over the array. I guess my confusion was in thinking that `data` was the array. thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Yes, the variable passed to your callback is set to whatever `JSON.parse()` returns. In your case an object containing the array, but if you changed your JSON it could be the array. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your JSON, what you have is an object with 1 property, which is an array of strings.

Using developer tools, you should set a breakpoint inside the $.getJSON success callback function to inspect the value of data. You'll see that data is not an array, but that you should actually be going after `data.printImages`. Otherwise, your code looks OK to me.

Re: Your approach. It seems like a good idea to me. Some day you might change the static .json file out for a server processed file, and you probably wouldn't have to change the client side at all to do that, other than point at a different URL.

Comment: can you share some insight regarding the dev tools and how to inspect the value of data?

Comment: Exactly how you do it depends on which browser you are using, but basically it's the same process for any of them. Open the dev tools, go to "scripts", "debugger", or "sources" and find your Javascript code. Click on the left side, near the line numbers to add a breakpoint (or use the right-click context menu.) When you hit that point in your code, execution will stop and you can inspect/change variable values, look at the call stack, etc. All modern browsers and even IE let you debug JS code within the browser.

Comment: excellent! i'll look more into it...thanks again for the help, Andrew! :)